# TFS Burndown Ideal Trend

Tags: reporting-services, tfs, project-management, scrum, ssrs-2012

What is the difference between **Sprint Burndown chart in iteration view as (Image 1)** and **Sprint Burndown report in View Reports (rdl file) as Image 2**  ?

How the **Ideal Trend** Calculated in both? Is Capacity included in the calculation? what system states (In sprint, in progress,to do,... ) are used in the calculation for image 1 ?
[image]
[image]
Thanks in advance

Comment: Clearly, the second one has more colors and a more agreeable date label.  What exactly are you trying to ask?

Comment: I need to know how Ideal Trend is calculated in both charts (Kindly note that both charts are for the same sprint)

Answer (score 0):

The ideal trend is calculated by taking the sum of all work, dividing by the time available, and plotting based on agility to reach zero.

The data represented in each graph is what is different. The web graphs data is calculated using sequential "as of" WIQL queries for midnight of each day.

The RS graph queries the cube for sum data.

Comment: Thanks @MrHinsh, but I need to know how the ideal trend is calculated in each chart? Is Capacity included in the calculation?  what system states (In sprint, in progress,to do,... ) are used in the calculation of pic(1) chart?

Comment: ? Only in progress states are used and capacity is immaterial.